# User management app for Django's auth

Tags: django, authentication, pinax, user-management

I am working on a small Django site where every user who leaves a comment on the site gets an email with a password (email is the user name) to change the comment later on.

The site should also support functions for users to retrieve or reset passwords. For this simple task I wanted to use the Django auth capabilities.

**Is there a Django app which provides a simple package of user management (to reset or change a user's password) which I could incorporate in my site?**

Would packages like Pinax or Drupal help for this simple task? They seem to be the overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for an advanced profile-/account-module you could take a look at [django-userena](https://django-userena.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Some other options are listed in the [profiles-grid](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/profiles/) on Django Packages.

Comment: Does userena support administrative approval for new users?

Comment: Website no longer exists

Answer (score 4):

Reset and change password are both included in the standard [contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) views.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at [django-user-accounts](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/)